# How to take (length of the aliases field) out of score calculation

Tags: elasticsearch, search, elasticsearch-7

Suppose we have a documents of people with their name and array of aliases like this:

```
{
   name: "Christian",
   aliases: ["נוצרי", "کریستیان" ]
}
```

Suppose I have a document with 10 aliases and another one with 2 aliases
but both of them contains alias with value `کریستیان`.

The `length of field (dl)` for the first document is bigger than the second document
so the `term frequency (tf)` of the first document gets lower than the second one. eventually the score of the document with less aliases is bigger than another.

Sometimes I want to add more aliases for person in different languages and different forms because he/she is more famous but it causes to get lower score in results. I want to somehow take `length of the aliases field` out of my query's calculation.

Comment: Disable norms for the field "properties": {
    "title": {
      "type": "text",
      "norms": false
    }
  }

Comment: This just saved my day @jaspreetchahal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Norms](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/norms.html)
store the relative length of the field.

> How long is the field? The shorter the field, the higher the weight.
>   If a term appears in a short field, such as a title field, it is more
>   likely that the content of that field is about the term than if the
>   same term appears in a much bigger body field.

Norms can be disabled using PUT mapping api

```
PUT my_index/_mapping
{
  "properties": {
    "title": {
      "type": "text",
      "norms": false
    }
  }
}
```

Links for further study

1. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/scoring-theory.html#field-norm